# Set input gravity settings for xbox controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

"Gravity -> How fast will the input recenter. Only used when the Type is key / mouse button." - [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html)

How would I go about implementing it anyway? Should I simulate key presses and use unitys gravity implementation or do it myself?

Comment: Unity's input system is horrible. there is a great one on the Asset Store called ReWire and they are working on a new input system which can be used when downloaded manually. It's an experimental release. Personally I try to avoid the built in system. See https://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/04/12/developing-the-new-input-system-together-with-you/

Comment: I guess I'l have a look but I will probably go for a free alternative as 45$ is a tad to expensive for me.

Comment: I just wanted to provide another option :) the experimental system made by the Unity devs themselfs (The link I provided) is free.